# Can't get data attribute value from radio button but can from select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've written some code that allows me to determine which select option is to be checked based on what is saved to the mysql db. To be able for that to work I need to print value of a data attribute to a hidden input so that I can store the option selected.

My code is working just fine when it comes to the select options, but doesn't seem to be working with the radio buttons. I've put together a demo of the two in jsfiddle or example which can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ax5Q/

Here is the code, first the html:

```
<input data-checked="yes" type="radio" name="product-attr-wifi" value="100" checked />Yes
<input data-checked="no" type="radio" name="product-attr-wifi" value="200" />No
<br>
<input type="text" name="product-attr-wifi-checked" />
```

Here is the jquery:

```
var optionChecked = function (checkedInput, checkedOuput) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(checkedInput).bind("change", function () {
            var checkedValue = $(this).find(":checked").attr("data-checked");
            $(checkedOuput).val(checkedValue);
        });
        $(checkedInput).trigger("change");
    });
};

optionChecked('input[name="product-attr-wifi"]', 'input[name="product-attr-wifi-checked"]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of radio button, you don't have to use `find()` because `this` refers to the radio element which has the data attribute

```
var optionChecked = function (checkedInput, checkedOuput) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(checkedInput).bind("change", function () {
            var checkedValue = $(this).attr("data-checked");
            $(checkedOuput).val(checkedValue);
        });
        $(checkedInput).filter(':checked').trigger("change");
    });
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9gW89/)

Comment: Fantastic, this works perfectly! Prints instantly and when changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var optionChecked = function (checkedInput, checkedOuput) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(checkedInput).on("change", function () {
            var checkedValue = $(this).filter(':checked').attr("data-checked");
            $(checkedOuput).val(checkedValue);
        });
        $(checkedInput).filter(':checked').trigger("change");
    });
};
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5ax5Q/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is good but it didn't print the value on page load and only when the radio button was changed. I need to make sure there is a value at all times.